# MS SQL Server, ask password before drop specific DB

Tags: sql-server, password

I've got 2 databases which are very important for our organization. I would like to prevent an accidental drop/delete of them... Do you have any suggestion? I was thinking about asking a password before perform the drop. Is this possible in MS SQL Server?

Comment: Give people only the permissions they require instead of relying on failsafes.

Comment: I know this is the easy way to do that... Unfortunately in our organization everyone use the same user...

Comment: That is really a bad practice.

Comment: I know... But I'm not able to change this...

Comment: Let me guess, the user's name is `sa` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are operating in a very risky security environment by sharing a single user with all permissions. The quickest solution is to revoke DB_Owner on the shared account for each database but leave reader/writer/ddladmin/backupoperator/accessadmin. That will prevent the shared User from dropping any databases they are attached to but should still have control over all the innards of those particular databases. If you need a User aside from your System Admin accounts that can drop databases you can create it separately and only use it when necessary.

Comment: I think is the best solution for us...

Answer (score 10):

You should, as the comment says, rely on *permissions* for this.

Strictly speaking, is not possible to "ask password". Where would the password dialog even be *displayed*?? SQL Server is a client server product that accept commands from any client that uses the TDS protocol. That may be Management Studio, sqlcmd.exe, a PowerShell script, a ADO.Net SqlClient application. Anything.

If you must, then you can deploy, as a last resort, a [DDL trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx). A DDL trigger will not replace permissions, but it can prevent an *accidental* drop.

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON SERVER
FOR DROP_DATABASE 
AS 
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop databases!' 
   ROLLBACK;
```

You can enhance the logic to check for database name, my purpose is not to give you a copy-paste working code.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I meant in Management Studio... Anyway permissions would be the answer, but everyone in our company use the same user...

Comment: And don't forget to periodically check to make sure the trigger gets re-enabled once they do the drop! I know I'm guilty of disabling some of my triggers when working and not re-enabling them afterwards.